# Find the maximum average over a specific period, two tables

Tags: sql, join, max

My task sounds like this: "Select sales territory (name) with sales in May 2013 higher than the average monthly sales per sales territory (Use SalesTerritory, SalesHeader tables)." As I understand it, logically, I need to find what territory was the maximum average for May 2013, while I need to link two tables (the "name" field in the "salesterritory" table, the rest of the data in the second, but the "name" must be present).
I tried to divide the task into parts, and find at least a territory by id without a name, here is my code:

```
SELECT TerritoryID, MAX(avga.sal)
from (select YEAR(OrderDate) AS 'Year', MONTH(OrderDate) AS 'Month', TerritoryID, AVG(TotalDue) AS 'sal'
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader 
GROUP BY YEAR(OrderDate), MONTH(OrderDate), TerritoryID 
having YEAR(OrderDate)=2013) as avga 
group by TerritoryID
```

This result does not appear to be correct even at this stage. Please help how to do it right? At least without the second table.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this steps:

1. Separate this query into small queries that collect part of the data you want and make sense to you, for example: A query to select the sales territory (name) with sales in May 2013; another query that brings the average monthly sales by sales territory etc. This will help you understand parts of the main query that you will create.
2. You can now try this in one query. Perhaps *common table expressions* is an easier approach. Here are some examples: [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need both the average per territory in May 2013, but also the average across all territories for the same month. Note the use of `OVER()` in the query below. This clause enables to calculation of an average across multiple rows, which is ideal in this situation because we need to only return those territories that have their figures higher than the overall average.

```
select
      yyyy
    , mm
    , TerritoryID
    , territory_av
    , month_av
from (
      SELECT
          yyyy
        , mm
        , TerritoryID
        , territory_av
        , AVG(av_value) OVER() month_av
      FROM (
              SELECT
                  YEAR(OrderDate) AS yyyy
                , MONTH(OrderDate) AS mm
                , TerritoryID
                , AVG(TotalDue) AS territory_av
              FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
              WHERE YEAR(OrderDate) = 2013
                AND MONTH(OrderDate) = 5
              GROUP BY
                  YEAR(OrderDate)
                , MONTH(OrderDate)
                , TerritoryID
              ) AS derive1
        ) AS derive2
    ) AS derive3
WHERE territory_av > month_av
;
```

Don't use `having` as an alternative for `where`. Use `where`  to filter table data which reduces the data processed by `group by`. Use `having` to filter aggregated values which happens after `group by`.

Regarding filtering for May 2013, it is more efficient to NOT use functions on data to assist filtering in a where clause. A more generic way to select a date range (that does not require changing data via functions) is like this:

```
          WHERE OrderDate >= '2013-05-01'
            AND OrderDate <  '2013-06-01'
```

Syntax for dates differes amongst databases, you might need to convert the date literals into a date (or timestamp)

```
          WHERE OrderDate >= to_date('2013-05-01','yyyy-mm-dd')
            AND OrderDate <  to_date('2013-06-01','yyyy-mm-dd')
```

or, in SQL Server you could use this:

```
          WHERE OrderDate >= '20130501'
            AND OrderDate <  '20130601'
```